# How to pass two Values from specific row in view to Controller asp.net core mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

My goal is when I click the green check mark, it updates the field from 1 to 0 which will return and make the green check mark a red x. Here is a picture of my table for reference.

My Alerts.cshtml code:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                                    {

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Model[i].AppName
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Model[i].MonAlertsID
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Model[i].AlertType
                                            </td>


                                            <td>
                                                @Model[i].DisplayName
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <form class="form-inline ml-auto" asp-action="Alerts2" method="POST">
                                                    @if(@Model[i].Active == "1")
                                                    {

                                                    <button type="submit" name="changetoinactive"  asp-action="Alerts2" formmethod="POST" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-fab btn-fab-mini btn-round">

                                                        <i class="material-icons">done</i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    }
                                                    @if (@Model[i].Active == "0")
                                                    {
                                                        <button type="submit" name="notactive" id="notactive" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-fab btn-fab-mini btn-round">
                                                            <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    }
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>


                                    }
```

my controller:

```
public string Alerts2()
{         
}
```

How do I get the values of AppName and MonAlertsID to the controller from the Form on my cshtml page?

Comment: sorry my Image didnt come through, but it is just a table and on each row there is a green check mark for active or red x for inactive. Want to click either or and change to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `hidden` input type to post `AppName` and `MonAlertsID` to controller.Action parameters' names should be matched to the names of hidden inputs.

Alerts.cshml:

```
<td>
    <form class="form-inline ml-auto" asp-action="Alerts2" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="appName" value="@Model[i].AppName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="monAlertsID" value="@Model[i].MonAlertsID" />
        @if (@Model[i].Active == "1")
        {

            <button type="submit" name="changetoinactive" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-fab btn-fab-mini btn-round">

                <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </button>
        }
        @if (@Model[i].Active == "0")
        {
            <button type="submit" name="notactive" id="notactive" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-fab btn-fab-mini btn-round">
                <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
            </button>
        }
    </form>

</td>
```

Action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Alerts2(string appName, int monAlertsID)
{
    //save changes to database
    //...
    return RedirectToAction("Alerts");
}
```